# What does .SD stand for in data.table in R

Tags: r, data.table

`.SD` looks useful but I do not really know what I am doing with it. What does it stand for? Why is there a preceding period (full stop). What is happening when I use it?

I read: 
*`.SD` is a `data.table` containing the subset of `x`'s data for each group, excluding the group column(s). It can be used when grouping by `i`, when grouping by `by`, keyed `by`, and _ad hoc_ `by`*

Does that mean that the daughter `data.table`s is held in memory for the next operation?

Comment: `?data.table` was improved in v1.7.10, thanks to this question. It now explains the name `.SD` as per the accepted answer.

Answer (score 229, accepted):

`.SD` stands for something like "`S`ubset of `D`ata.table". There's no significance to the initial `"."`, except that it makes it even more unlikely that there will be a clash with a user-defined column name.

If this is your data.table:

```
DT = data.table(x=rep(c("a","b","c"),each=2), y=c(1,3), v=1:6)
setkey(DT, y)
DT
#    x y v
# 1: a 1 1
# 2: b 1 3
# 3: c 1 5
# 4: a 3 2
# 5: b 3 4
# 6: c 3 6
```

Doing this may help you **see** what `.SD` is:

```
DT[ , .SD[ , paste(x, v, sep="", collapse="_")], by=y]
#    y       V1
# 1: 1 a1_b3_c5
# 2: 3 a2_b4_c6
```

Basically, the `by=y` statement breaks the original data.table into these two sub-`data.tables`

```
DT[ , print(.SD), by=y]
# <1st sub-data.table, called '.SD' while it's being operated on>
#    x v
# 1: a 1
# 2: b 3
# 3: c 5
# <2nd sub-data.table, ALSO called '.SD' while it's being operated on>
#    x v
# 1: a 2
# 2: b 4
# 3: c 6
# <final output, since print() doesn't return anything>
# Empty data.table (0 rows) of 1 col: y
```

and operates on them in turn.

While it is operating on either one, it lets you refer to the current sub-`data.table` by using the nick-name/handle/symbol `.SD`. That's very handy, as you can access and operate on the columns just as if you were sitting at the command line working with a single data.table called `.SD` ... except that here, `data.table` will carry out those operations on every single sub-`data.table` defined by combinations of the key, "pasting" them back together and returning the results in a single `data.table`!

Comment: Yes, exactly. Another way to see `.SD` is `DT[,print(.SD),by=y]`.

Comment: @MatthewDowle -- While you're here, a question for you. Doing `DT[,print(.SD[,y]),by=y]`, indicates that I do have access to the value of `y`, even though it's not a part of `.SD`. From where is the value of `y` being scoped? Is it available b/c it's the current value of `by`?

Comment: @Josh Nice. Yes. The `.SD[,y]` is a regular `data.table` subset so since `y` isn't a column of `.SD` it looks in the environment that called it, which in this case is the `j` environment (of the `DT` query) where the `by` variables are available. If not found there, it looks in the parent, and its parent and so on in the usual R way. (Well, via join inherited scope, too, which isn't being used in these examples because there are no `i`s).

Comment: @Josh FAQ 2.8 has more on this, might need improving (suggestions welcome).

Comment: @MatthewDowle Thanks. I'll chew on that, since I don't yet grok why a search for `y` will find the value of `by`. Re: the documentation, that *is* something I'd like to help with at some point, since I like your package so much but wouldn't be any help with the `C`-level coding you use to implement it. Cheers, J.

Comment: @Josh Because the group variables are available in j, too, and are length 1. `by=list(x,y,z)` would mean `x`,`y` and `z` are available to `j`. For generic access they're wrapped up in `.BY` too. FAQ 2.10 has some history on it, but some clarity could be added to `?data.table`. Great, docu help would be very welcome. Even better if you'd like to join project and change directly.

Comment: Another option besides `DT[ , print(.SD), by = y]` is `DT[ , dput(.SD), by = y]`, which I find can be even more helpful for simple `data.table`s.

Comment: How can I use .SD on the left side (row selection)?
For example DT[apply(.SD, 1, function(r) any(r %in% "myvalue")),output]

Answer (score 118):

### Edit:

Given how well-received this answer was, I've converted it into a package vignette now available [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-sd-usage.html)

---

Given how often this comes up, I think this warrants a bit more exposition, beyond the helpful answer given by Josh O'Brien above.

In addition to the **S**ubset of the **D**ata acronym usually cited/created by Josh, I think it's also helpful to consider the "S" to stand for "Selfsame" or "Self-reference" -- `.SD` is in its most basic guise a *reflexive reference* to the `data.table` itself -- as we'll see in examples below, this is particularly helpful for chaining together "queries" (extractions/subsets/etc using `[`). In particular, this also means that `.SD` is *itself a `data.table`* (with the caveat that it does not allow assignment with `:=`).

The simpler usage of `.SD` is for column subsetting (i.e., when `.SDcols` is specified); I think this version is much more straightforward to understand, so we'll cover that first below. The interpretation of `.SD` in its second usage, grouping scenarios (i.e., when `by =`  or `keyby =`  is specified), is slightly different, conceptually (though at core it's the same, since, after all, a non-grouped operation is an edge case of grouping with just one group).

---

Here are some illustrative examples and some other examples of usages that I myself implement often:

#### Loading Lahman Data

To give this a more real-world feel, rather than making up data, let's load some data sets about baseball from `Lahman`:

```
library(data.table) 
library(magrittr) # some piping can be beautiful
library(Lahman)
Teams = as.data.table(Teams)
# *I'm selectively suppressing the printed output of tables here*
Teams
Pitching = as.data.table(Pitching)
# subset for conciseness
Pitching = Pitching[ , .(playerID, yearID, teamID, W, L, G, ERA)]
Pitching
```

### Naked `.SD`

To illustrate what I mean about the reflexive nature of `.SD`, consider its most banal usage:

```
Pitching[ , .SD]
#         playerID yearID teamID  W  L  G   ERA
#     1: bechtge01   1871    PH1  1  2  3  7.96
#     2: brainas01   1871    WS3 12 15 30  4.50
#     3: fergubo01   1871    NY2  0  0  1 27.00
#     4: fishech01   1871    RC1  4 16 24  4.35
#     5: fleetfr01   1871    NY2  0  1  1 10.00
#    ---                                       
# 44959: zastrro01   2016    CHN  1  0  8  1.13
# 44960: zieglbr01   2016    ARI  2  3 36  2.82
# 44961: zieglbr01   2016    BOS  2  4 33  1.52
# 44962: zimmejo02   2016    DET  9  7 19  4.87
# 44963:  zychto01   2016    SEA  1  0 12  3.29
```

That is, we've just returned `Pitching`, i.e., this was an overly verbose way of writing `Pitching` or `Pitching[]`:

```
identical(Pitching, Pitching[ , .SD])
# [1] TRUE
```

In terms of subsetting, `.SD` is still a subset of the data, it's just a trivial one (the set itself).

## Column Subsetting: `.SDcols`

The first way to impact what `.SD` is is to limit the *columns* contained in `.SD` using the `.SDcols` argument to `[`:

```
Pitching[ , .SD, .SDcols = c('W', 'L', 'G')]
#         W  L  G
#     1:  1  2  3
#     2: 12 15 30
#     3:  0  0  1
#     4:  4 16 24
#     5:  0  1  1
# ---         
# 44959:  1  0  8
# 44960:  2  3 36
# 44961:  2  4 33
# 44962:  9  7 19
# 44963:  1  0 12
```

This is just for illustration and was pretty boring. But even this simply usage lends itself to a wide variety of highly beneficial / ubiquitous data manipulation operations:

### Column Type Conversion

Column type conversion is a fact of life for data munging -- as of this writing, [`fwrite` cannot automatically read `Date` or `POSIXct` columns](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1450), and conversions back and forth among `character`/`factor`/`numeric` are common. We can use `.SD` and `.SDcols` to batch-convert groups of such columns.

We notice that the following columns are stored as `character` in the `Teams` data set:

```
# see ?Teams for explanation; these are various IDs
#   used to identify the multitude of teams from
#   across the long history of baseball
fkt = c('teamIDBR', 'teamIDlahman45', 'teamIDretro')
# confirm that they're stored as `character`
Teams[ , sapply(.SD, is.character), .SDcols = fkt]
# teamIDBR teamIDlahman45    teamIDretro 
#     TRUE           TRUE           TRUE
```

If you're confused by the use of `sapply` here, note that it's the same as for base R `data.frames`:

```
setDF(Teams) # convert to data.frame for illustration
sapply(Teams[ , fkt], is.character)
# teamIDBR teamIDlahman45    teamIDretro 
#     TRUE           TRUE           TRUE 
setDT(Teams) # convert back to data.table
```

The key to understanding this syntax is to recall that a `data.table` (as well as a `data.frame`) can be considered as a `list` where each element is a column -- thus, `sapply`/`lapply` applies `FUN` to each *column* and returns the result as `sapply`/`lapply` usually would (here, `FUN == is.character` returns a `logical` of length 1, so `sapply` returns a vector).

The syntax to convert these columns to `factor` is very similar -- simply add the `:=` assignment operator

```
Teams[ , (fkt) := lapply(.SD, factor), .SDcols = fkt]
```

Note that we must wrap `fkt` in parentheses `()` to force R to interpret this as column names, instead of trying to assign the name `fkt` to the RHS.

The flexibility of `.SDcols` (and `:=`) to accept a `character` vector *or* an `integer` vector of column positions can also come in handy for pattern-based conversion of column names*. We could convert all `factor` columns to `character`:

```
fkt_idx = which(sapply(Teams, is.factor))
Teams[ , (fkt_idx) := lapply(.SD, as.character), .SDcols = fkt_idx]
```

And then convert all columns which contain `team` back to `factor`:

```
team_idx = grep('team', names(Teams), value = TRUE)
Teams[ , (team_idx) := lapply(.SD, factor), .SDcols = team_idx]
```

** *Explicitly* using column numbers (like `DT[ , (1) := rnorm(.N)]`) is bad practice and can lead to silently corrupted code over time if column positions change. Even implicitly using numbers can be dangerous if we don't keep smart/strict control over the ordering of when we create the numbered index and when we use it.

### Controlling a Model's RHS

Varying model specification is a core feature of robust statistical analysis. Let's try and predict a pitcher's ERA (Earned Runs Average, a measure of performance) using the small set of covariates available in the `Pitching` table. How does the (linear) relationship between `W` (wins) and `ERA` vary depending on which other covariates are included in the specification?

Here's a short script leveraging the power of `.SD` which explores this question:

```
# this generates a list of the 2^k possible extra variables
#   for models of the form ERA ~ G + (...)
extra_var = c('yearID', 'teamID', 'G', 'L')
models =
  lapply(0L:length(extra_var), combn, x = extra_var, simplify = FALSE) %>%
  unlist(recursive = FALSE)

# here are 16 visually distinct colors, taken from the list of 20 here:
#   https://sashat.me/2017/01/11/list-of-20-simple-distinct-colors/
col16 = c('#e6194b', '#3cb44b', '#ffe119', '#0082c8', '#f58231', '#911eb4',
          '#46f0f0', '#f032e6', '#d2f53c', '#fabebe', '#008080', '#e6beff',
          '#aa6e28', '#fffac8', '#800000', '#aaffc3')

par(oma = c(2, 0, 0, 0))
sapply(models, function(rhs) {
  # using ERA ~ . and data = .SD, then varying which
  #   columns are included in .SD allows us to perform this
  #   iteration over 16 models succinctly.
  #   coef(.)['W'] extracts the W coefficient from each model fit
  Pitching[ , coef(lm(ERA ~ ., data = .SD))['W'], .SDcols = c('W', rhs)]
}) %>% barplot(names.arg = sapply(models, paste, collapse = '/'),
               main = 'Wins Coefficient with Various Covariates',
               col = col16, las = 2L, cex.names = .8)
```

[image: fit OLS coefficient on W, various specifications, depicted as bars with distinct colors.]

The coefficient always has the expected sign (better pitchers tend to have more wins and fewer runs allowed), but the magnitude can vary substantially depending on what else we control for.

### Conditional Joins

`data.table` syntax is beautiful for its simplicity and robustness. The syntax `x[i]` flexibly handles two common approaches to subsetting -- when `i` is a `logical` vector, `x[i]` will return those rows of `x` corresponding to where `i` is `TRUE`; when `i` is *another `data.table`*, a `join` is performed (in the plain form, using the `key`s of `x` and `i`, otherwise, when `on =`  is specified, using matches of those columns).

This is great in general, but falls short when we wish to perform a *conditional join*, wherein the exact nature of the relationship among tables depends on some characteristics of the rows in one or more columns.

This example is a tad contrived, but illustrates the idea; see here ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31329939/conditional-keyed-join-update-and-update-a-flag-column-for-matches), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29658627/conditional-binary-join-and-update-by-reference-using-the-data-table-package)) for more.

The goal is to add a column `team_performance` to the `Pitching` table that records the team's performance (rank) of the best pitcher on each team (as measured by the lowest ERA, among pitchers with at least 6 recorded games).

```
# to exclude pitchers with exceptional performance in a few games,
#   subset first; then define rank of pitchers within their team each year
#   (in general, we should put more care into the 'ties.method'
Pitching[G > 5, rank_in_team := frank(ERA), by = .(teamID, yearID)]
Pitching[rank_in_team == 1, team_performance := 
           # this should work without needing copy(); 
           #   that it doesn't appears to be a bug: 
           #   https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1926
           Teams[copy(.SD), Rank, .(teamID, yearID)]]
```

Note that the `x[y]` syntax returns `nrow(y)` values, which is why `.SD` is on the right in `Teams[.SD]` (since the RHS of `:=` in this case requires `nrow(Pitching[rank_in_team == 1])` values.

## Grouped `.SD` operations

Often, we'd like to perform some operation on our data *at the group level*. When we specify `by =` (or `keyby =` ), the mental model for what happens when `data.table` processes `j` is to think of your `data.table` as being split into many component sub-`data.table`s, each of which corresponds to a single value of your `by` variable(s):

[image: A visual depiction of how grouping works. on the left is a grid. The first column is titled "ID COLUMN" with values the capital letters A through G, and the rest of the data is unlabelled, but is in a darker color and simply has "Data" written to indicate that's arbitrary. A right arrow shows how this data is split into groups. Each capital letter A through G has a grid on the right-hand side; the grid on the left has been subdivided to create that on the right.]

In this case, `.SD` is multiple in nature -- it refers to each of these sub-`data.table`s, *one-at-a-time* (slightly more accurately, the scope of `.SD` is a single sub-`data.table`). This allows us to concisely express an operation that we'd like to perform on *each sub-`data.table`* before the re-assembled result is returned to us.

This is useful in a variety of settings, the most common of which are presented here:

### Group Subsetting

Let's get the most recent season of data for each team in the Lahman data. This can be done quite simply with:

```
# the data is already sorted by year; if it weren't
#   we could do Teams[order(yearID), .SD[.N], by = teamID]
Teams[ , .SD[.N], by = teamID]
```

Recall that `.SD` is itself a `data.table`, and that `.N` refers to the total number of rows in a group (it's equal to `nrow(.SD)` within each group), so `.SD[.N]` returns the *entirety of `.SD`* for the final row associated with each `teamID`.

Another common version of this is to use `.SD[1L]` instead to get the *first* observation for each group.

### Group Optima

Suppose we wanted to return the *best* year for each team, as measured by their total number of runs scored (`R`; we could easily adjust this to refer to other metrics, of course). Instead of taking a *fixed* element from each sub-`data.table`, we now define the desired index *dynamically* as follows:

```
Teams[ , .SD[which.max(R)], by = teamID]
```

Note that this approach can of course be combined with `.SDcols` to return only portions of the `data.table` for each `.SD` (with the caveat that `.SDcols` should be fixed across the various subsets)

*NB*: `.SD[1L]` is currently optimized by [*`GForce`*](https://jangorecki.gitlab.io/data.table/library/data.table/html/datatable-optimize.html) ([see also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22137591/about-gforce-in-data-table-1-9-2)), `data.table` internals which massively speed up the most common grouped operations like `sum` or `mean` -- see `?GForce` for more details and keep an eye on/voice support for feature improvement requests for updates on this front: [1](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/735), [2](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/624), [3](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/523), [4](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/971), [5](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1197), [6](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1414)

### Grouped Regression

Returning to the inquiry above regarding the relationship between `ERA` and `W`, suppose we expect this relationship to differ by team (i.e., there's a different slope for each team). We can easily re-run this regression to explore the heterogeneity in this relationship as follows (noting that the standard errors from this approach are generally incorrect -- the specification `ERA ~ W*teamID` will be better -- this approach is easier to read and the *coefficients* are OK):

```
# use the .N > 20 filter to exclude teams with few observations
Pitching[ , if (.N > 20) .(w_coef = coef(lm(ERA ~ W))['W']), by = teamID
          ][ , hist(w_coef, 20, xlab = 'Fitted Coefficient on W',
                    ylab = 'Number of Teams', col = 'darkgreen',
                    main = 'Distribution of Team-Level Win Coefficients on ERA')]
```

[image: A histogram depicting the distribution of fitted coefficients. It is vaguely bell-shaped and concentrated around -.2]

While there is a fair amount of heterogeneity, there's a distinct concentration around the observed overall value

Hopefully this has elucidated the power of `.SD` in facilitating beautiful, efficient code in `data.table`!

Comment: Good explanation. Just one comment: Instead of Teams[ , .SD[which.max(R)], by = teamID], you can exploit the fast data.table order function: via Teams[order(teamID,-R) , .SD[1L], keyby = teamID], this should be faster.

Comment: @bartleby thanks, indeed this is correct, but the general approach is still useful to know -- e.g. if we need to order by a group-dependent quantity. perhaps I'll change the example.

Answer (score 5):

I did a video about this after talking with Matt Dowle about .SD, you can see it on YouTube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DwEzQuYfMsI

Comment: Unfortunately, Stack Overflow usually doesn't welcome answers that consist essentially of outside links. Maybe you want to edit more text and code info into it? Fyi Matt has added your video to the wiki: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Presentations