# '*ply" functionality in R data table

Tags: r, data.table

I am looking for a way to use the split-apply-combine strategy with R's `data.table` package.

```
library(data.table)

# take a data.table object, return integer
func <- function(DT) 
{
   DT$a * DT$a
}

DT = data.table(
  a = 1:50
  # ... further fields here
  b = rep(1:10, 5)
)

# this obviously won't work:
DT[, result:=func, by=b]

# but this will (based on @Aruns answer below)
DT[, result:=func(.SD), by=b]
```

While this here is very simple `data.table`, with more complicated structures, I'd like to be able to extract logic into functions and send subsets as `data.table`s to them, without having to enlist all field names.

Comment: @Arun, i've edited the question a bit, i was not aware of the `.SD` will be in a moment, though.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Edit:** Check out the more detailed HTML vignettes available on the [project wiki of data.table](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started).

Okay, let me show you a small comparison of `plyr` method using `data.table` to show the equivalence. Maybe that'll help to get you started. But it is important that you read [**this very nice introduction to data.table**](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-intro.pdf) AND [**this FAQ**](http://datatable.r-forge.r-project.org/datatable-faq.pdf).

```
set.seed(45) # for reproducibility
# dummy data
m  <- matrix(10*sample(15, 100, replace=T), ncol=10) # 100*10 matrix
df <- data.frame(grp = sample(1:10, 100, replace = T))
df <- cbind(df, as.data.frame(m))
```

You have a data.frame with 11 columns, 10 data and 1 grouping column. Now, if you'd want to take the mean of each of these columns within each group, then, using `plyr`, you'd do something like:

```
require(plyr)
ddply(df, .(grp), function(x) colMeans(x[, 2:11]))
```

Using `data.table`, you can use `.SD` (check [**this post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8508482/what-does-sd-stand-for-in-data-table-in-r) for a nice explanation of what `.SD` is, in addition to reading the documentation links).

```
require(data.table)
dt <-data.table(df, key="grp")
dt[, lapply(.SD, mean), by=grp]
```

This should get you started, I think..?

Comment: Hey - this is very nice, thanks alot! Basically everything I was looking for was the `.SD` feature.