# Aggregate all columns of data.table, without having to reference them by name

Tags: r, aggregate, data.table

I'd like to do the equivalent of the following, but with data.table's "by":

```
dt <- data.table(V1=rnorm(100), V2=rnorm(100), V3=rnorm(100), ...
                 group=rbinom(100,2,.5))
dt.agg <- aggregate(dt, by=list(dt$group), FUN=mean)
```

I know that I could do this:

```
dt.agg <- dt[, list(V1=mean(V1), V2=mean(V2), V3=mean(V3)), by=group]
```

But for the case I'm considering I have 100 or so columns V1-V100 (and I always want to aggregate all of them by a single factor, as in aggregate above) so the data.table solution I've got above isn't feasible.

Comment: For reference, among the copious examples in `?data.table` is the following: `DT[,lapply(.SD,sum),by=x]`.

Comment: @joran, could you please explain the role of .SD?

Comment: `.SD` refers to subset of data.

Comment: `.SD.` means "all columns, other than the one(s) used in the grouping by-expression". Please read [What does .SD stand for in data.table in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8508482/what-does-sd-stand-for-in-data-table-in-r). In this case, `.SD` is equivalent to `.(V1,V2,V3)` or `list(V1,V2,V3)`, but it's faster than  explicitly referencing them by name.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

```
dt[, lapply(.SD, mean), by=group]
```

To specifiy columns:

```
dt[,...,by=group, .SDcols=c("V1", "V2", "V3", ...)]
dt[,...,by=group, .SDcols=names(dt)[1:100]]
```