# Non-fuzzy join to lookup table on exact match to partial string

Tags: r, data.table

I'm trying to join a column of data to a lookup table. However, the data will *contain* the text in the column of the lookup table (but may contain arbitrary text before and after it).

This sounds similar to [fuzzyjoin two data frames using data.table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55550325/fuzzyjoin-two-data-frames-using-data-table) , but fuzzy matching won't work here. I need an exact match with a certain string and to ignore everything before and after. For example, I need "Jo Billiam" to match to "Jo", and not to "William".

Example data:

```
library(data.table)
data <- data.table(full.name=c('Jonathan Parker', 'Mr. Jonathan Smith', 'S. Patrick Jones'))
lookup <- data.table(name.long=c('William', 'Patrick', 'Jonathan'),
                     name.short=c('Bill', 'Pat', 'John'))
```

Desired Output:

```
data.table(full.name=c('Jonathan Parker', 'Mr. Jonathan Smith', 'S. Patrick Jones'),
            nickname=c('John', 'John', 'Pat'))
```

The two ideas I've had so far are:

1. Use grepl with sapply to effectively loop through the whole lookup table
2. Use grep to strip out anything that doesn't match one of the lookup strings, and then do a normal data.table join on that stripped out version.

Both of these seem quite inelegant though: is there a better way of doing this?

*NB. In my data I don't have to worry about matching more than one lookup string*

Comment: So what then? A simple merge?? Also next time you think your Q is not a dupe, just comment under your Q. Don't ask same thing twice as you fill the site with 'noise'

Comment: Thanks for your advice. The message I got from Stackoverflow was "If this question doesn’t resolve your question, ask a new one." It didn't, so I thought that asking a new question, more clearly phrased, was what was being recommended to me. Since the previous question has already been closed, I didn't think "noise" should be a significant issue either.

Comment: Key word there: 'New one' :) . I m reading it now. I ll try and help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using SQL we can perform a left join on the indicated condition.  The column names must be escaped using [...] because dot is an SQL operator. The double pipes mean string concatenation such that the expression involving them produces a string of the form `%...%` where % is a wildcard matching any string.

```
library(sqldf)

sqldf("select D.*, L.[name.short]
  from data D
  left join lookup L on d.[full.name] like '%' || L.[name.long] || '%'")
```

giving:

```
           full.name name.short
1    Jonathan Parker       John
2 Mr. Jonathan Smith       John
3   S. Patrick Jones        Pat
```

We can alternately use the `instr` function which is like `grepl(..., fixed = TRUE)`.  It gives the same output.

```
sqldf("select D.*, L.[name.short]
  from data D
  left join lookup L on instr(d.[full.name], L.[name.long])")
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer - this works perfectly on the test data, so I'll accept it if no better one comes along. Unfortunately when I applied it to my real data it failed, as my data has a few exotic classes of data in which sqldf can't handle. I can get around this by getting fewer columns from sqldf and then joining back to my original data. Still, I wish there were a more elegant (and faster) solution...

Answer (score 1):

Maybe fuzzyjoin::regex_left_join solves your problem.

1. Create a regex column: Find name.long and ignore eveything around

```
library(fuzzyjoin)
library(tidyverse)

lookup <- lookup %>% 
    mutate(regex = paste(".*\\b", name.long, "\\b.*", sep = ""))
```

2. Joyn the tables by regex

```
output <- regex_left_join(data, 
                          lookup, 
                          by = c(full.name = "regex"))
```

3. Select columns

```
output %>% 
  select(full.name, name.short)
```